# VS Debugging: Attach to a process that hasn't startet

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In Visual Studio I can attach the debugger to any process that is currently running. 
I have an application that is calling my DLLs and what I need is to debug this process from it's beginning. Is this possible?

Comment: See if https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the project properties (context menu, Properties or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Go to the Debug tab
3. Choose "Start external program"
4. Save and close
5. Choose debug mode
6. Run the application (<kbd>F5</kbd>)

If the application expects the DLL in a specific path, it may be necessary to add a post build step to copy the DLL to the expected location.

Comment: your answer works for C# DLLs, for C++ it's a bit different. As @qxg mentioned, both solutions are described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx